# Scripts inside SyncFusion tab not firing

Tags: javascript, html, syncfusion

Currently working on an older system which runs on MVC .Net 4.5 - hoping to modernise it by levying SyncFusion and their controls.

I am attempting to load SyncFusion (EJ2) tabs dynamically and load the content into a tab.
On the system, this will use an ajax call to return a partialview - but for the sake of the example on StackBlitz it's a simple string with a JavaScript alert.
For some reason, the contents scripts are not firing, as shown in the included StackBlitz.

After speaking with SyncFusion support I was assured their controls do support this, but for the life of me I cannot figure out why it isn't working?

Link to StackBlitz showing the issue
https://stackblitz.com/edit/lcb5rz-5milao

Line 24 of index.js - shows `<script>alert('test');</script>` when the tab is rendered, the alert is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

We have validated the reported query at our end and have achieved the requirement with the help of the code shown below. Please refer to the sample and code snippets.

**[index.js]**

```
function AddTab(args) {
  if (!gridAdded && tabObj.items.length - 1 === args.selectedIndex) {
    let contentHtml = document.createElement("div");
    contentHtml.setAttribute("id", "Grid");
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.text =
      "var grid = new ej.grids.Grid({columns: [{ field: 'OrderID', headerText: 'Order ID', textAlign: 'Right', width: 120, type: 'number' },{ field: 'CustomerID', width: 140, headerText: 'Customer ID', type: 'string' }, { field: 'Freight', headerText: 'Freight', textAlign: 'Right', width: 120, format: 'C' },{ field: 'OrderDate', headerText: 'Order Date', width: 140, format: 'yMd' }]});grid.appendTo('#Grid');";
    contentHtml.appendChild(script);
    var item3 = [{ header: { text: "Grid" }, content: contentHtml }];
    tabObj.addTab(item3, 3);
    tabObj.selectedItem = tabObj.items.length - 1;
    gridAdded = true;
  }
```

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/ej2-js-tab-add-items-dynamically-sample-vkesht?file=index.js

Regards,
Ravikumar Venkatesan